# A Chinese（adjective or noun）population

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> A city with a large **Chinese** population.

Is the word "Chinese" in question an adjective or an noun?

I ask because it helps me to decide which version is correct:

Many cities with large **ethnic** Chinese populations.

Many cities with large **ethnically** Chinese populations.

Answer (score 2):

> a city with a large Chinese population

*Chinese* in the above noun phrase is an adjective.

This adjective forms with others a series of cumulative adjectives, as shown below.

> many cities with large ethnic Chinese populations

*large ethnic Chinese* in the above noun phrase are cumulative adjectives.

> "Cumulative adjectives" are two or more adjectives that build on one another and together modify a noun. They're consecutive.

[ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cumulative-adjectives-1689815)

*ethnic Chinese* is more common than *ethnically Chinese*; hence, the following NP

> many cities with large ethnic Chinese populations

is better than the other one you are also considering.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ethnic+Chinese%2Cethnically+Chinese+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true)